# Possible to setup ODBC connection through code in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, odbc

I have some reports that I made with an odbc connection. I now put it on production and the reports will not run as it seems to be looking for the development odbc connection and not using the production one.

I tired giving both odbc connections the same name but that did not work. Is it possible to set it up through code to switch to the right odbc connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the coding portion of your question, but I would open the report go to "Database", "Set Datasource Location" and update to the production ODBC.  Then save and close the report.